# Function returns generator object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to populate a nested dictionary with a path to a file. First I unzip a file bundle for each node in the cluster. Then I have a function that creates a dictionary for every zip file.
This is for python 3.8.

The structure is like this:
`ZipFile_2020-01-22-09-11-24_2020-01-22T14_56_54.905 {'node': None, 'xml': None, 'perops': None, 'access': None, 'logs': None}`

Now I am trying to find and add the path to an xml file. I can find the file ok and I can populate the nested dictionary but it's a: `<generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>`.

What is the best way to deal with this? How to a convert the generator object to the file path?

Here is the function:

```
def nodefile():
    supportzips = {}.fromkeys(list((filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(x), os.listdir('.')))),{}.fromkeys(list(['node','xml','perops','access','logs'])))
    for k,v in supportzips.items():
        supportzips[k]['xml'] = glob.iglob('./**/application-properties/application.xml')
    return supportzips
```

Output:

````
Bitbucket_support_2020-01-22-09-11-24_2020-01-22T14_56_54.905 {'node': None, 'xml': <generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>, 'perops': None, 'access': None, 'logs': None}
<generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>
Bitbucket_support_2020-01-22-09-14-11_2020-01-22T14_56_49.965 {'node': None, 'xml': <generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>, 'perops': None, 'access': None, 'logs': None}
<generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>
Bitbucket_support_2020-01-22-09-11-57_2020-01-22T14_56_53.231 {'node': None, 'xml': <generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>, 'perops': None, 'access': None, 'logs': None}
<generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>
Bitbucket_support_2020-01-22-09-12-49_2020-01-22T14_56_51.505 {'node': None, 'xml': <generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>, 'perops': None, 'access': None, 'logs': None}
<generator object _iglob at 0x7f9c544bfba0>```
````

Comment: The `i` in `iglob` indicates that you want an iterator instead of a list. If you want to immediately consume the iterator just use `glob.glob`

Comment: On an unrelated note, six months from now you're going to hate yourself for having written the function this way. Consider unpacking this into several lines of code that are easier to debug when something inevitably goes wrong.

Comment: Both `iglob()` (and `glob()`) effectively return multiple things, so it's unclear why you're expecting them to return in a single item (a path to an xml file).

Comment: At the very least, `supportzips = dict.fromkeys(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir('.')),
            dict.fromkeys(['node','xml','perops','access','logs']))` is equivalent to the first line of your function while being shorter and a little easier to read.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions and info. I will try to clean that up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glob.iglob()` function is supposed to be used in a memory efficient way, that is it does not create data in memory until evaluation is required. From the documentation:

> Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without actually storing them all simultaneously.

If what you really expect from your call to `iglob` is a single file, you better use `glob` which returns a `list` of matching items, or force evaluation on the generator by enclosing it in a `list` or a `tuple` constructor.

```py
# Force evaluation
supportzips[k]['xml'] = tuple(glob.iglob('./**/application-properties/application.xml'))[-1]

# Use glob instead
supportzips[k]['xml'] = glob.glob('./**/application-properties/application.xml')[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for info. It sort of worked for me. The only issue is that I have same file of each.

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget to choose the answer that solved your issue: it's your duty to be a well grounded community citizen of stackoverflow, and no one can do it in your place. Thank you.